# Finding the index after matching substring in R

Tags: r

I'm using the grep command to check whether a string is present in a list.

```
a <- list("IK" , "IK /// CHGB ", "IKM" ,"HGIKGF", "IK2" ,"IK2FGH" )
```

I am trying to obtain the index of the strings which contain the substring "IK" using grep

```
grep("IK",a)
```

gives

```
[1] 1 2 3 4 5 6
```

I would like to get the index of strings that contain only "IK" or "IK" followed by a single character or separated by /// e.g `"IK /// CHGB" , "IK2"` `and "IKM"`. I don't intend to output the index of a strings like `"HGIKGF" or "IKHGFTR /// BN"`.

The desired output is

```
[1] 1 2 3 5
```

I would like to ask for suggestions on how this can be done.

Edit1: Please note, the string that I am matching for "IK" is stored in a list.

```
Matchfor <- list("IK","UK")
for(j in 1:length(Matchfor){
grep(Matchfor[j],a)
}
```

Comment: I think that you want `grep("IK\\w?\\b",a)`

Comment: Why use a `list` instead of a character vector?

Comment: @G5W Works perfect! Please check my edit. "IK" is in a list. Could you please suggest how `grep("IK\\w?\\b",a)` can be modified?

Comment: @Gregor I can use a character vector too.

Comment: Do you want one list of matches for each string in Macthfor or do you want one big list for all strings?

Comment: @G5W One big list for all strings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Slightly extending your test case `a` to include an example of "UK.

```
a <- list("IK" , "IK /// CHGB ", "IKM" ,"HGIKGF", "IK2" ,"IK2FGH", "UK")
Matchfor <- c("IK","UK")
MatchPat <- paste0(Matchfor, "\\w?\\b")
lapply(MatchPat, grep, a) 
[[1]]
[1] 1 2 3 5

[[2]]
[1] 7
```

A bit of explanation: `\\w?` optionally allows one character after the main pattern (IK or UK).  `\\b` indicates a word boundary  - a non-word character or the end of the string.

Comment: I tried for this test case `a<- list("RFC2",     "IGFBP2",   "IGFBP2.1", "IGFBP2.2", "FGFBP2" ,  "FBP2")`. The output is `[1] 2 3 4 5 6`.I am matching for  `Matchfor <- c("FBP2")` . I was expecting the output will be 6. Could you please suggest what has gone wrong?

Comment: I think that you are saying that you also want nothing in front of the `FBP2`.   To specify that You also need `\\b` in front of the pattern. Try `MatchPat <- paste0("\\b", paste0(Matchfor, "\\w?\\b"))`